# How can I override the cancel words in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is it possible to override words like: `quit`, `goodbye`, `exit` so that the the not doesn't quit?

I tried creating an intent adding a collection of quit words like this:

[image]

But it still falls down to the termination intent and the program closes.

Is it possible to override these so that the program doesn't quit when the user tells it to quit?

Answer (score 1):

In short - no. These are built into the Actions on Google platform to make sure that users can exit an ill-behaved Action that doesn't provide any other way to exit. These are standard - users will be used to using a phrase such as this if they *want* to exit or stop what is going on.

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense. An di know that it's why it behaves like that.. the thing is that for my personal use, this should be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You add 'actions_intent_CANCEL' to the Events of your intent, in addition to the training phrases. That way it can handle the in-built cancel.

This is so you can add your own relevant utterances. However, if you're doing this so users won't be able to quit, it probably won't get certified.

Comment: This is an app only for my personal use. I will never get it approved. The thing with that is that it gives me an error because it has to be a termination intent. I can't call other intents from here, or it will crash...